# Euler characteristic when the base space admits a finite good cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am trying to solve Exercise 14.37 on the differential-form book by Bott and Tu:

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be any map and $\{U\}$ a finite good cover of $Y$. Show that the Euler characteristics of $X$
\begin{eqnarray}
\chi(X)=\sum_{p,q}\sum_{\alpha_{_0}<\cdots<\alpha_p}(-1)^{p+q}\text{dim }H^q(\pi^{-1}U_{\alpha_{_0}\cdots\alpha_p}).
\end{eqnarray}

It seems that the proof would follow if the spectral sequence stops at $E_2$, but it cannot be the case in general. I guess that the ''finite good cover'' should have been used somewhere.

Comment: Typically, the differentials in a spectral sequence preserve the "Euler characteristic": the alternating sum of the dimensions of the vector spaces forming the spectral sequence.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Many thanks for the helpful comment (or answer)! It seems that "goodness" of the cover is not necessary.